# Styles contradicts with my HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created one travel page via HTML and CSS and I have added button to add another trip in the same but after clicking on the button more than 5 times the form is getting out of region. It seems the issue is coming from styles but i am unable to figure out the same.

[Click here to replicate the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/1bmyxqyv/6/)

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Add another trip</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a minimal example of the relevant problem *here*, not somewhere offsite in a 200-line HTML and 9000-line CSS.

Comment: The problem here I think it is that you messed up with bootstrap alignment. The class `row` have both `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `-15px` and `col-*`'s (which should be direct children of `row`'s) have `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `15px` so if you keep adding `col-*`'s and no `row`'s (or taking care of padding's and marginss)  the content of those `col-*`'s won't be properly align. That's as much as I say after seeing only one `row` in your example. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **JSFiddle** and found the issue.
You have to add following class in your css.

```
form .form-row{margin-left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have this in your css :

```
.form-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

here `margin-left: -5px` makes the content moves to left every time the element is created then change `margin-left: -5px' to`margin-left: 0px`.

After changing Css your css will look like this

```
.form-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way you are adding the new form sections when clicked on the 'Add another trip' is wrong. The `<div class="form-new" id="space"></div>` element that you have placed to insert the new form section is inside the previous `<div class="form-row"></div>`. You should not place it there but just after it. Try to understand with this example.

This is what you have now.

```
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-new" id="space"></div>
</div>
```

Try making it this way,

```
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="form-new" id="space"></div>
```